# error in ubuntu work in codeblocks?

Tags: c, ubuntu, codeblocks

I want to know why while compiling my code in ubuntu this message appears

```
    $*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000024dd190 ***
```

but the same code works without any error in code::blocks and gives me the right results ?? I need your help to fix this error .

I've tried to update the compiler but that doesn't work?!

Update:

the error appears when executing this statement:

```
    $first_array = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long*));
```

I don't see that there's any error in it, Yes??

Comment: You'll need to show the relevant code. You've got a memory corruption bug somewhere in it.

Comment: @Mat but why codeblocks compile it without giving any error!

Comment: Memory corruption bugs are undefined behavior in C. Undefined behavior can do anything, _including appearing to work perfectly fine_.

Comment: @Mat Could you see the error line in the update?

Comment: Use `valgrind` to try and figure out where your problem is. The fact that it's failing on a malloc or a free is unsurprising. Those functions will sometimes detect that you've corrupted memory. The real problem is somewhere before that call, quite possibly in a completely unrelated function.

Comment: `$first_array` is not a portable identifier, I recommend against using that. `malloc`ing `sizeof(unsigned long*)` to an `unsigned long*` is dubious. But the cause of the error is probably an earlier out-of-bounds write that corrupted `malloc` data and triggers the segfault upon that `malloc` coincidentally.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a size in memory equal to the size of a pointer, not an unsigned long, you should rather use:

```
first_array = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
```

If you were on a 32 bit system, your first code would allocate 4 bytes in memory, which you then point to with a pointer to a 8 byte data structure. You need to allocate the size of the variable, not the size of the pointer.